# Javascript get window height after setting it

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code to resize the window after a soft keyboard event:

```
var viewheight = window.innerHeight;
var viewwidth = window.innerWidth;
window.addEventListener('resize', function (e) {
    var newviewheight = window.innerHeight;
    var newviewwidth = window.innerWidth;
    if (((viewheight - newviewheight) / viewheight) > 0.35 && ((viewwidth - newviewwidth) / viewwidth) < 0.01) {
        window.innerHeight = viewheight;
    }
})
```

When I normally trigger an orientation change, it will give me the new window height perfectly:

```
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', function () {
    setTimeout(getnewhw, 1000);
})
function getnewhw() {
    viewheight = window.innerHeight;
    viewwidth = window.innerWidth;
    document.getElementById('heighttxt').value = viewheight;
}
```

However, after I trigger the resize event with the keyboard, the orientation function seems to always give me the last value assigned to "window.innerHeight" and never updates, almost like I've created a new variable. Any reason why this is happening?

Edit:
Here is what happens to the height.

Onload (landscape orientation) height 400

On portrait orientation change height 800

On landscape orientation change height 400

On keyboard event height 400 -> 250 (trigger resize) -> 400

From this point on, the height will always be 400 no matter what resize or orientation event is triggered.

On portrait orientation change height 400 (wrong, should be 800)

On keyboard event height 400 --> 400 (fails condition)

Comment: Are you sure your IF is important? Does it really get through? My guess is that your resize does not fulfill the condition.

Comment: See edit where I show how it is failing

Comment: `window.innerHeight` is read-only. Maybe the browser you use allows to overwrite it, but then it stops to calculate real height and simply returns the assigned value? (like replacing a getter method with a primitive value)